# How to find wildcard match in formula?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, formula

I'm comparing two columns matching a cell value in "P26" and if i find a match, output that value in the second column to the current cell i have this formula in. This formula works, I was wondering if there is a way to find a wildcard match from my value P26 lets say "1234*" instead of just a exact match "1234" ? Something like match "like" P26?

columns look like this, P26= "3 OK"   <--- the "OK" is the wildcard part. i need to match the "3" in column 1 then output column 2 to the cell value.

```
1             12345
2             64578
3             56465
```

This formula is in a cell value:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(AF4:AF31,MATCH(P26,AE4:AE31,0)),"---")
```

Comment: `MATCH(P26 & "*"`,...`

Comment: @ScottCraner i'm assuming the wildcard could be anything not just a "*", it could be 1234DSFJLDSJFLSDKJFlkSJDF or 1234IIiioos232.

Comment: Something MATCH("like" P26,....)

Comment: Did you try it? the `*` is a wildcard in this instance not the literal `*`.

Comment: Yes, i've tried and it doesn't work but look at post edit.

Comment: Works for me see: http://imgur.com/a/e0zDM

Comment: @ScottCraner it works if the wildcard is on the column searching for, i'm looking to search the value as the wildcard in those two columns. I'm looking for the other way around.

Comment: So P26 is the longer value while the columns are the shorter partial value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an Array formula like this:

```
=INDEX(B1:B5,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1:A5,D1)),0))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]